# Convergence of dual product of weakly and strongly convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Say $V$ is a <s>reflexive></s> Banach space, <s>so that we can identify the dual of the dual $V'$ with $V$, i.e. $(V')'=V$</s>.

Consider two sequences $\{v_k\} \subset V$ and $\{f_k\} \subset V'$ that converge to $v\in V$ and $f\in V'$ in the strong and in the weak sense, i.e.

- $v_k \to v$ in $V$ and
- $f_k \rightharpoonup f$ in V'

as $k \to \infty$. How to show, that

- then $\langle v_k, f_k \rangle \to \langle v, f \rangle$ in $\mathbb R$,

where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the dual pairing on $V\times V'$?

---

I see that for the seperate sequences $\langle v_k, f \rangle$ and  $\langle v, f_k \rangle$ both converge <s>(the latter because of reflexivity of $V$)</s> [see comments below] but I haven't come to terms with the mutual convergence.

Comment: I don't think that you need reflexivity. This looks like a general fact of Banach spaces.

Comment: Maybe. You need to get from $\langle f_k,v''\rangle \to \langle f,v''\rangle$ for any $v'' \in V''$ to $\langle f_k,v\rangle \to \langle f,v\rangle$ for any $v \in V$.

Comment: Which you always can do in Banach spaces, since there is a [norm-preserving injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Normed_spaces) $J\colon V \to V''$

Comment: Oh well, I had missed that point. Since you spoke of "weak convergence in $V'$" I had automatically assumed that it was what is usually called *weak*-$\star$ convergence, that is $$\lvert\langle f_k - f, v\rangle\rvert\to 0, \quad \forall v \in V.$$
With this notion of convergence everything goes on fine as in Davide's proof. You need Banach-Steinhaus's theorem to ensure that the sequence $f_j$ is norm bounded.

Comment: If your sequence converges in *weak* sense, meaning that 
$$\lvert \langle f_k-f, v''\rangle\rvert \to 0, \quad \forall v''\in V'', $$
then better still: using the norm-preserving injection that you have rightfully recalled we can prove that the sequence converges in weak-$\star$ sense too, and we are finished.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still tend to feel lost in $\infty$ dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write 
$$|\langle f_k,v_k\rangle-\langle f,v\rangle|\leqslant \lVert f_k\rVert\cdot\lVert v_k-v\rVert+|\langle f_k,v\rangle-\langle f,v\rangle|,$$
and notice that the sequence $(\lVert f_k\rVert,k\geqslant 1)$ is bounded.